# Add Raster Layer from Min.IO (s3) Bucket with authentication to QGIS

Tags: qgis, cloud-gis, s3

Is it possible to add a Raster Layer from a TIFF stored in a Min.IO bucket  (with authentication) to QGIS?

In this [changelog](https://qgis.org/ru/site/forusers/visualchangelog330/index.html) this is mentioned:

> Feature: S3 Cloud Storage Support S3 compatible cloud storage, such as AWS S3 and MinIO, are now supported as a method for accessing and storing external files, made available by using the external storage UI for cloud storage of attachments. A new QGIS Auth method named «AWS S3» has been provided to support connecting to services using the S3 protocol. This feature was funded by Métropole Grand Lyon** This feature was developed by Jacky Volpes

Documentation:

- https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#drivers-supporting-virtual-file-systems
- https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html#gdal-configuration-file
- https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#vsis3

My attempt following the guidelines:

1. Created AWS config file at: `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.aws\config`

[image]

2. Created User Environment variables:

[image]

3. In `QGIS tried Layer > Add Layer > Add Raster Layer`

[image]

And all I get is:

[image]

Any Ideas?